# Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon

Tags: flutter, dart

I Try almost all Solution That I found on Internet  But my problem  is Still not solved.
I  Open gradle.properties and I add The Below code  It doesn't help me,

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

I also  delete .gradle directory then I try building again. But The Problem Still Exists. Please I want Help?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024M -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\likec\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7-all\cuy9mc7upwgwgeb72wkcrupxe\gradle-6.7\lib\gradle-launcher-6.7.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.7
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 1048576 bytes for AllocateHeap
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\likec\.gradle\daemon\6.7\hs_err_pid14492.log
```